Probability that two elements commute in a noncommutative simple finite group
Good afternoon !
Let $G$ a finite non-abelian group. Let $p_G$ the probability that two elements randomly chosen commute. It is well known that : $$p_G \leqslant \frac{5}{8}$$
The upper bound is optimal (if we consider for example $\mathbb{D_4}$ the dihedral group of the square or the quaternion group $\mathbb{H_8}$), and there is no interesting lower bound because of the symmetric group $S_n$ for example.
We can even show with Burnside's lemma that : $$p_G = \frac{k_G}{|G|}$$
With $k_G$ the number of conjugacy classes in $G$.

I've seen that if moreover we suppose $G$ simple (i.e $G$ has only trivial normal subgroups), we have : $$p_G \leqslant \frac{1}{12}$$
I would love to prove it. What I tried so far :
It is sufficient to show that if $k_G \geqslant \frac{|G|}{12}$, then $k_G = \frac{|G|}{12} = 5$.
There are $k_G$ irreducible representations of degree $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_{k_G}$, with $d_1 = 1$ (trivial representation), $d_1 \leqslant \dots \leqslant d_{k_G}$ and $d_1^2 + \dots + d_{k_G}^2 = |G|$.
$G$ is simple so the only irreducible representation of degree 1 is the trivial representation.
We can show that : $$d_2 = 3$$
Indeed G is simple so it has no irreducible representations of degree 2.
Furthermore if $d_2 \geqslant 4$ then $|G| \geqslant 1 + 16(k_G - 1)$, so by the inequality $k_G \geqslant \frac{|G|}{12}$ we have $|G| \leqslant 15$, which is impossible because the smallest simple non-abelian subgroup is $A_5$, and $|A_5| = 60 > 15$.
From now I don't know how to conclude. We have : $$12k_G \geqslant |G|= 1 + 3^2 + \dots + d_{k_G}^2$$
And I don't know what to say. Any help ? :(

I'm guessing the result about simple groups relies on the Classification of Finite Simple Groups. If my guess is right, then there may not be such an elementary proof.

@coiso Steve D's answer shows that we do not need CFSG to prove this. It can be done using results that date back to to the 19th century!

You can eliminate the $d_2=3$ case by looking at possible finite subgroups of $SU(3,\mathbb{C})$, because your group is perfect and finite, so you can use Weyl's trick. The simple ones are fairly well-known I think ($A_5$ and $PSL(2,7)$), for references see this MO answer.
Another approach which I couldn't make work was to note that for the reverse inequality to hold, you need at least one element whose centralizer has index $\le12$ in $G$, which gives an embedding into $A_{12}$. But that's as far as I got.

You could assume the subgroup of $A_{12}$ was primitive, and primitive permutation groups of degree up to $17$ were classified by Jordan in 1872: Camille Jordan. Sur l’énumeration des groupes primitifs pour les dix-sept pre-
miers degrés. C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, 75:1754–1757, 1872.

@DerekHolt very nice! GAP shows only 13 simple primitive subgroups, and they're the usual suspects, so perhaps easy to case-by-case weed out. One can also use the fact that this for any subgroup $H\le G$, $p_H\ge p_G$, so finding an $A_5$ subgroup in each of these primitive subgroups is also enough.
